# Is there a starting WP Theme that matches mint.com/blog?

Tags: wordpress-theming

Trying to save some time by starting with a Wordpress theme that matches Mint.com's layout structure. Anyone have a suggestion for a good starting point?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/) It's a very good starter theme, that is responsive, HTML5, and has SSAS and Less support. It already has a similar layout to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [themeforest](http://themeforest.net/user/asifiqbalsumon/portfolio?ref=asifiqbalsumon), you will find many similar themes.